# Different behaviour of two similar blocks of code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
// Block - 1
var moduleToBind = {
  name: 42,
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var unboundGetName = moduleToBind.getName;
console.log(unboundGetName());

var boundGetName = unboundGetName.bind(moduleToBind);
console.log(boundGetName());
// End Block -1
// Output :
//
// 42
```

```js
// Block - 2 having similar code
var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

var unboundGetX = module.getX;
console.log(unboundGetX());

var boundGetX = unboundGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX());
// End Block - 2
// Output :
// undefined
// 42
```

I checked the JavaScript code in Chrome version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox version 60.0.2 (64-bit).

Though in node it gives the same result of undefined and 42 for both blocks.

Comment: `console.log(window.name)` will explain where it is coming from

Comment: I don't see any references to the second block of code.  It is unclear how its relevant.

Comment: @Amy, um there are two sections in his snipplet? Seems relevant to me.

Comment: @epascarello I see no references to that block of code.  Where is it used?  Where is `module` referenced anywhere?  Do you understand now?

Comment: Really you do not see on that uses this.name (first) and one that uses this.x (second)

Comment: @epascarello Yes I see that.  That isn't what I asked.

Comment: wait... did you not scroll the snipplet and see the lines of code where it executes it? `var unboundGetX = module.getX; console.log(unboundGetX()); ...`

Comment: @epascarello Man I feel dumb now.  I didn't notice the scroll bar.  I'll leave my comments up as a testament to my shame.

Comment: @Amy Thank you so much for trying to help :), I think i should have created two blocks differently from start, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue here is the context of this and the choice of a variable name.

So `this` when you run code is the `window` and window has a [name property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), but it does not have an `x` property.

So `this.name === window.name`

If you would define a property x on the window object such as `window.x = "foo"` before your code, you would get the same type of result as the `this.name` one.

Comment: Thank you for the help :). That was very helpful.